# (preg_match ('#^/thank-you/hello/#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

Tags: php

So basically I'm trying to select all content that is in `/thank-you/hello/`, so this can be `/thank-you/hello/x/`, `/thank-you/hello/y/`, `/thank-you/hello/z/`, etc.

This is what I'm using right now:

```
preg_match ('#^/thank-you/hello/#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

This block of code only works for stuff that is in `/thank-you/hello/`.

How should I change this snippet to include all the other folders that are after `/hello/`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read more about `regex`

I also recommend [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/) to test and study the site

In the desired pattern you can replace the desired word from `.*?`

`.`: Matches any character other than newline (or including line terminators with the /s flag)

`a*`: Matches zero or more consecutive `a` characters.

`a?`: Matches an `a` character or nothing.

They may seem a little incomplete without their examples

I suggest you see their examples on [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/)

**example:**

```
preg_match('#^/thank-you/hello/.*?/#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

It may not be exactly what you want
Or something may increase or decrease later and you may want to make a change

I think everyone should learn `regex` so that they can implement what they want according to their own desires.

**I do not think it is a good idea to use patterns that you do not know what they mean**